# RemotePlayer CanPause is always set to false

Tags: google-cast

I am using the Chromecast Chrome API alongside the Default Receiver for integrating chromecast into a project. I am creating the `RemotePlayer` and `RemoteController`.

Recently we lost the ability to play, pause and adjust the volume so I looked into what was going on. I cam now see that the `RemotePlayer` is initialised it has the values of `RemotePlayer.canPause` and `RemotePlayer.canControlVolume` set to `true`. but after the instantiation of the `RemoteController` these values change to `false`

```
if (!this._remotePlayer) {
  this._remotePlayer = new cast.framework.RemotePlayer();
  this._remotePlayer.canControlVolume = true;
  this._remotePlayer.canPause = true;
  this._remotePlayer.canSeek = this.isLive() ? false : true;
}

// settings are correct canPause => true, canControlVolume => true 

if (!this._remoteController) {
  this._remoteController = new cast.framework.RemotePlayerController(this._remotePlayer);
  // settings are incorrect canPause => false, canControlVolume => false
}
```

I am stuck as to how to inform the receiver that it should allow play and pause and volume adjustments.

Comment: Please file a bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:190205%20status:open&s=modified_time:desc

Comment: I have ;) 
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69118296

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an attempt to stop others who may have this headache in the future, you need to wait until `loadMedia` has resolved successfully before creating your instances of the `RemotePlayer` and `RemoteController`